# How to release a Scala library to Maven Central using sbt?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, maven-central, sbt-release

I have an open source Scala project using SBT and I would like to release my library to Maven. How do I do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I always forget how to do this. So here are my notes:

### Once in your life:

1. Create [Sonatype account](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/Signup!default.jspa)

### For every new developer machine:

1. Install `gpg` e.g. on OSX: `brew install gpg`
2. Run `gpg --gen-key` to generate a new key. **Remember the passphrase and email you used**.
3. Make sure you see it when you list your secret keys:

   ```
   > gpg --list-secret-keys
   ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
   -----------------------------------
   sec   rsa2048 2019-06-13 [SC] [expires: 2021-06-12]
         F5003E5C4718B1F466B244F766AA02EC8AA60DB9
   uid   [ultimate] Pathikrit Bhowmick <pathikritbhowmick@msn.com>
   ssb   rsa2048 2019-06-13 [E] [expires: 2021-06-12]
   ```
4. Publish your key:

   ```
   > gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys F5003E5C4718B1F466B244F766AA02EC8AA60DB9

   gpg: sending key 66AA02EC8AA60DB9 to hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
   ```

You can also publish your key manually by copy the key

```
  > gpg --armor --export F5003E5C4718B1F466B244F766AA02EC8AA60DB9
```

And submitting it here http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/

4. Verify that key got published by searching [gnupg.net](http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?search=0xF5003E5C4718B1F466B244F766AA02EC8AA60DB9) or [keyserver.net](https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=0xF5003E5C4718B1F466B244F766AA02EC8AA60DB9). *This may take up to a day to show up*
5. Add `default-key` to your `gpg.conf`:

   ```
   > cat ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
   default-key F5003E5C4718B1F466B244F766AA02EC8AA60DB9
   ```
6. Append following to this file (`~/.sbt/${SBT_VERSION}/sonatype.sbt`):

   ```
   credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "oss.sonatype.org", "<your username>", "<your password>")
   ```

### For each new project:

1. Create [new JIRA issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?issuetype=21&pid=10134) using your Sonatype account to request new repo
2. Wait till [above issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-18266?filter=-2) is resolved
3. Add `sbt-pgp`, `sbt-release` and `sbt-sonatype` as a plugin to your project. Here is an example [plugins.sbt](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt):

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz"  %   "sbt-release"             % "1.0.0")
   addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth"       %   "sbt-pgp"                 % "1.0.0")
   addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt"     %   "sbt-sonatype"            % "0.5.1")
   ```
4. Here is an example [build.sbt](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/blob/master/build.sbt) that I use for multi-projects.

### For each new release:

1. You may have to do `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to let `gpg` do password prompt in command line like below:
   [image]
2. `sbt +release` (will prompt for passphrase that you created for `gpg`)

   1. Note: The `+release` cross releases across your specified `crossScalaVersions`. If you have `pushChanges` enabled in your build to push your commit to git remote, make sure you do `pushChanges` once only on the last `crossVersion`.
3. View artifact on [Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/pathikrit/) (the snapshot versions are [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/pathikrit/)). If you cannot see it there you can double check the [Nexus Repository Manager](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~better-files)
4. Wait few hours for it to propagate to [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/pathikrit/)

### Starting Over

- Sometime release may fail midway and your repository might be stuck in staging. You then have to go to https://oss.sonatype.org > Login > Staging Repositories > Find your repo > Click Drop e.g.
  [image]

Comment: I'm trying to `sbt>module/publishSigned`. It throws the error: 
`[error] gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=2d)
[error] gpg: keydb_search failed: Invalid packet
[error] gpg: no default secret key: Invalid packet
[error] gpg: signing failed: Invalid packet`

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Do we need to run sbt publishSigned after sbt +release or not?

Comment: @Pranjut: No you don't if you have configured the `release` task like I have

Comment: Also, Maven Central will stop supporting `com.github.*` from April 2021, the alternative is to use `io.github.*`
https://central.sonatype.org/changelog/#2021-04-01-comgithub-is-not-supported-anymore-as-a-valid-coordinate

Comment: By the way, here the official sbt documention for uploading jars to Maven Central -> https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Using-Sonatype.html