# Rollback failed release process

Tags: scala, publishing, revert, sbt-release, sbt-sonatype

Publishing a library is not an atomic operation in my project because the process involves number of side-effects that need to be cleaned up in the case of a failure. Errors can occur due to timeouts, attempting to publish an already existing version, staging repo already existing, problems with signing key, etc. Currently the manual steps I perform to rollback a botched release consist of

1. Login to [Sonatype Nexus](https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories) and drop staging repository
2. Remove version increase commit: `git reset --hard sha`
3. Remove tag: `git tag -d name`

Is there a way to make the publishing process atomic such that all the changes are reverted automatically on failure?

My project's release process is similar to [How to release a Scala library to Maven Central using sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963559/how-to-release-a-scala-library-to-maven-central-using-sbt) namely

```
releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
    checkSnapshotDependencies,
    inquireVersions,
    runClean,
    runTest,
    setReleaseVersion,
    commitReleaseVersion,
    tagRelease,
    publishArtifacts,
    setNextVersion,
    commitNextVersion,
    releaseStepCommand("sonatypeReleaseAll"),
    pushChanges
  )
```

where `plugins.sbt` has

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz"        %   "sbt-release"                 % "1.0.11")
addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth"             %   "sbt-pgp"                     % "2.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt"           %   "sbt-sonatype"                % "2.5")
```